# Firebase on Android : DataSnapshot.getValue() causes current activity to end

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my user class :

```
public class User {

public String name;
public int number;
public String title;
public String company;
public String location;
public Bitmap image;
public String name_title_company_location;
public static int uid = 0;

public User() {
    // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
}

public User(String name, int number, String title, String company, String location, Bitmap image) {
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
    this.title = title;
    this.company = company;
    this.location = location;
    this.image = image;
    this.name_title_company_location = name + "_" + title + "_" +company + "_" + location;
    uid++;
}
```

}

This is my Firebase databse :

```
 users
      1
       company:"Indifair"
       image
       location:"Bangalore"
       name:"Anupam Singh"
       name_title_company_location:"Anupam Singh_Engineer_Indifair_Bangalore"
       number:956156494
       title:"Engineer"
```

I am using this code to read from database :

```
            public class QueryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_query);

    Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            EditText t1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText10);
            EditText t2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText11);
            EditText t3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText13);
            EditText t4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText14);

            final String s1 = t1.getText().toString();
            final String s2 = t2.getText().toString();
            final String s3 = t3.getText().toString();
            final String s4 = t4.getText().toString();

            mDatabase.child("users").orderByChild("name_title_company_location")
                    .equalTo(s1 + "_" + s2 + "_" + s3 + "_" + s4)
                    .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    User user = userSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                            }
                        }

                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            // Getting Post failed, log a message
                            //Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                        }

                    });
                 }
            });
          }
        }
```

When I click button3 current activity ends and control goes to parent activity. If I comment out

```
  User user = userSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
```

the problem is gone.

There is no error or exception in Logcat. I have added correct dependencies in build.gradle.

What could be going wrong?

Comment: If you say "no error or exception in Logcat", how does it end?

Comment: You are getting error it mean there is not data `for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    User user = userSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                            }`

Comment: verify t1 ,t2,t3, t4  not null

Comment: You have created **three** separate thread for same question. It looks weird and waste of time.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59608298/firebase-on-android-datasnapshot-getchildrencount-is-returning-0 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59600313/android-with-firebase-datasnapshot-getvalue-throws-java-lang-illegalargument

Comment: in logcat set log level to error and in drop down next to Regex select No Filters, and check if you can c error

Comment: @Alex Mamo Control goes to parent activity

Comment: @Md. Asaduzzaman No they are not same questions, each raises different issue.

Comment: @ked Still no error.

Answer (score 1):

I thought the user class should extend to something. e.g `public User extends.....() {
    // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
}

public User(String name, int number, String title, String company, String location, Bitmap image) {
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;.....`